# Can I block while using two weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried using a weapon in both hands: a dagger in one and a sword in the other. But I soon realized that I could not parry, since each mouse button is used to swing a weapon. Is there another way to parry when both hands are occupied?

Comment: M'aiq the Liar has the dialogue possibility "Don't try blocking if you have two weapons. You will only get confused. Much better to hit twice anyway." -- a reference to the inability to block when dual-wielding

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No there is not.

The only way to block/parry attacks, is to have either only one weapon, or a weapon and a shield, and then press (and hold) right mouse button.

Answer (score 5):

Dual wield in game-land is always a tradeoff: you are doubling your offense in exchange for defense. So it could be seen as a balancing choice on Bethesda's part. Equally, it could have been forced on us by the people who play the game on consoles and their lack of buttons.

IRL, dual-wielding is done for the opposite reasons. You gain off-hand defense, but you'd not normally want to attack with it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=9247) that allows parrying (effectively blocking) while dual wielding. There are several options available on how it will handle using 2 keys to do 3 things.